# RavenDb, Aggressive Cache, and timeouts

Tags: ravendb

I have a few dozen servers that are performing thousands of tasks every minute.  Each task requires loading of 3 objects from RavenDb.  These objects change VERY infrequently, like 20-30 changes per day (out of millions of calls to Raven to get them).

I was advised to use Aggressive Caching to minimize on the load on my RavenDb which I did and which worked.

However, when there are communication issues between my worker servers and Raven server, agressively cached loads from Raven fail with timeouts.  How can I prevent the client from even looking at Raven if it didn't receive a notification that object has changed, and just using their cached values?  Is there perhaps size to the cache that I can configure if it doesn't hold everything in memory by default?

Comment: What do you mean: "agressively cached loads from Raven fail with timeouts"

Comment: When some communication issues (ie networking problems) occur between worker instances and Raven, my client calls to load objects time out, at least some of them. I assumed that clients would be retrieving data from cache without even bothering the server where communication is severed

Answer (score 0):

Aggressive cache means that the client will serve requests directly from the cache if it can. But it doesn't have to.

In particular, a document may not be in the cache (it might have been evicted), or we might need to go to the server to see if it is up to date because we got a notification about doc changes.

You can't assume that aggressive caching will not hit the server, indeed, they are counted against your requests per session quota.

Comment: Right, which is my original question, how can I increase size of the client cache, so evictions are less frequent